# Different Cypress baseUrl for cy.visit() and cy.request()

Tags: cypress

Our application under test locally has a frontend and backend that run on **localhost:4200** and **127.0.0.1:8000**, respectively.

When calling `cy.visit('/somepage')` we would like this to have a different `baseUrl` than for `cy.request('/someapi')` as `cy.visit()` will visit a page hosted on the frontend, while `cy.request()` will make a request to an API endpoint on the backend.

We can use the default `baseUrl` config from `cypress.json` for `cy.visit()`, but is there a way to have `cy.request()` default to a different config setting than the default `baseUrl` it uses out of the box? Trying to avoid having to specify this all over the place like `cy.request(<fully qualified domain name> + '/someapi')`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use config file cypress.env.json to store your API url and get it from each test case.

In your cypress.env.json

```
"apiUrl": "http://api"
```

In your test case

```
describe('get the api variable from config file', () => {
    //set up the variables
    const apiUrl = Cypress.env('apiUrl');
    cy.request(apiUrl + '/someapi');
```

Comment: cypress should let us get rid of such boilerplate

Comment: @Stuck I guess the 80/20 rule applies... If you need it, cypress lets *you* add a custom command: just `Cypress.Commands.add("api", (urlPath)=> cy.request(Cypress.env('apiUrl') + urlPath)` and then you can `cy.api('/someapi')` to your heart's content :)

Comment: @conny you mean what I wrote in my answer 2 month ago? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about a feature in cypress that allows configuring different `baseUrl`s for `visit` resp. `request`.

Since you want to get rid of the boilerplate of setting up the correct API uri per test you could also write a custom command around `cy.request`:

*cypress/support/commands.js*

```
import { API_URI } from '../constants';
// you may want to add a more suitable wrapper depending on the params/options you need to support.
Cypress.Commands.add('api', uri => cy.request(API_URI + uri));
```

*your_spec.js*

```
describe('Foor', () => {
  it('Baar', () => {
    cy.api('/someapi')...
  });
});
```

**BONUS HINT**: Be aware that in case no fully qualified domain name (FQDN) is given to `cy.request()` it behaves [stateful](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Arguments) by either using the uri of the last `cy.visit` call or as a fallback `baseUrl` from cypress config. The approach of this answer is not effected from it, because it always sets the FQDN.